Avoiding double clone conditionally
I have a check method which takes (and needs) ownership of a big vector I have, and outputs a boolean value. If it outputs true, then I set structs field to this vector. It looks something like this:
fn my_func(&mut self, v: Vec<u8>) {
    if self.check(v.clone()) {
        self.v = v;
    }
}

check method can not take slice, even if it does it would just have to clone it inside, so it is not gonna solve anything.
My question is, is there a way to clone v only if check returns true and I need to set the struct's v field? Because currently, if check returns false, I unnecessarily cloned the v, which potentially carries quite big data (around 1 MB).

You could modify check to take the vec and then return it in addition to the bool (or as a Result). Then it can internally decide whether cloning is necessary or if the unmodified vec can be returned.

But the problem with this is that in the check method I consume the array to create a HashMap in conjunction with other certain variables. So for me to return it I again have to clone the vec, but just inside the check method.

You can't consume the vec and have it without cloning. It hasn't worked for cakes when baking and it doesn't work for Rust when programming.
